# Javarscript issues with dynamic tooltipster

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

I'm using [Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) which seems to be a nice jquery plugin.

Regardless I need to have my tooltips dynamic, which I don't believe should be that difficult. However I wrote a script and maybe it's because I'm tired or I don't know the simplest of javascript. Probably a combination of both.

I can't seem to get around this particular error. TypeError: $(...).tooltipster is not a function.

Here is the basic javascript code:

```
$("img#box_image[data-img-number]").hover(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
        i = $(this).attr("data-img-number");
        var w = "http://trailerbrokerimages.s3.amazonaws.com/pics/" + i  ;
        window.console.log('before tool');
        window.console.log('before tool ' +w);
        tool(w);
});
var tool = function (w) {
$('.tooltip_two').tooltipster({content: $('<span><img   style="height:191px;                                                                                width:256px;"src="http://trailerbrokerimages.s3.amazonaws.com/pics/'+w+'" /></span>')});
```

An example of the code can be found at http://www.trailerbroker.com/go/listings/view/219

I suspect it's lame mistake on my part, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same id `box_image` for multiple elements.

I understand that you're trying to make it unique by appending the `data-img-number`, but this won't work, as there's no way you can do this at run time unless your explicitly specifying different `hover` handlers.

Instead you could attach the `hover` handler to a class.

Add a `class="box_image"` to your `<img />` elements and attach the `hover` as follows,

```
$(".box_image").hover(//rest of your code here//)
```

This should give you the desired functionality.

Comment: That made sense, so made the appropriate changes. However, I'm still getting the following error TypeError: $(...).tooltipster is not a function. I am capturing the correct data id, I just can't seem to pass it to the tooltipster?

Comment: @Chad I just checked the code on the link you've provided, put your in side `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()`

Comment: I updated the code, but I can't seem to get it work.  It's back to the original issue TypeError: $(...).tooltipster is not a function. I'm missing something really simple...

Comment: @Chad There's a problem with the minified version of the file, change the src to point to the unminified version of the file. That should help. Download a fresh version from 

http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/

Comment: @Chad The minified version doesn't contain a `$.fn` or a `$.extend` which are "mandatory" for writing a plugin.

Comment: @Turan I made the changes to no effect. Thanks for all your help, I emailed iamceege, to what's up with their code. I'll keep you posted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using twitter bootstrap popover. Don't waste your time with tooltipers.